# Let Customers to Input a fixed product quantity in quantity box using a button or radio button in the product page in Prestashop 1.7.x

Tags: prestashop-1.7

Greetings of the Day!

I need to have the condition on the product page where we can let our customers input a fixed product quantity in quantity box using a button or radio button in the product page along with the default functionalities with the add to cart mechanism.

Why I need this is because I am using the product volume discount list on the product page and I want the customer to select the quantity directly from the mentioned list.

Pls, find the screenshot attached for reference.

[Screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPv73.png)

Customers can select the quantity directly from the red rectangle shown in the image through a button/radio/link click.

Hope somebody will help me out with this for which I would be greatly obliged.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

to achieve that you should change the responsible tpl file, unless there is an override you should find it in  `/themes/YOUR THEME NAME/templates/catalog/_partials/product-add-to-cart.tpl`

There look for the block `{block name='product_quantity'}`, right after you will see the input used for it, just build your html structure being aware that you should keep the same name and probably also the same standard classes (but you can add yours as well).

After that style your new radio input in `/themes/YOUR THEME NAME/assets/css/custom.css` and the trick is done.

I hope you are familiar with tpl/smarty if you have to inject some vars from php, in case you don't need that it is just pure html and css.

Hope my answer helped.

Simone